# Count the number of occurrences in array/hash with specific value

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, hash

This is related to a [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73461956/counting-how-many-keys-with-specific-value-in-array-of-hashes) where some users kindly tried to helped me but at the time I couldn't reproduce the problem exactly.

**STARTING POINT**

```
output = [{:selected_person=>true,
           :full_name=>"Fn G猫gèksöugöynúõr Ln Ýüćėūpàøehwìėwo",
           :address_1=>"Trzy Lipy", :address_2=>"20", 
           :postal=>"34-567",
           :city=>"Gdańsk", :country_code=>"PL"}, 
          {:selected_person=>true,
            :full_name=>"Fellow Fellow Last Name", :minor=>false}]
```

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

Count the number of occurrences of `:selected_person` as `true` in the output

**WHAT I HAVE NOW**

**A. Returns '2' (counts the number of occurrences no matter the value)**

```
output.count { |h| h[:selected_person] = true }
```

**B. Returns '0'**

```
output.count { |h| h[:selected_person]}
```

**EDIT NOTES:**

After saving, I didn't notice that the example changed so the link shows a version where version B would work, as pointed out in one answer, but the correct `output`/starting point is the one pasted here in the question and in the screenshot

[image: Correct Context]
[Example](https://replit.com/@CarlaGomes1/Stack#main.rb)

Answer (score 1):

By using a single equal in your block, you're *setting* `:selected_person` to `true` for each item, not checking it if is true.

Either of these would work. Make sure you're running it against a new `output`, not one that may have been mutated by the single equals experiment.

```rb
output.count { |h| h[:selected_person] == true }
output.count { |h| h[:selected_person] }
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer but, my bad, I hadn't noticed that when I saved the code in the provided link, it changed the code so indeed, your suggestions would work in that case but not in my case (screenshot and output code in the question). Please check my edited question

Comment: The code you link to has a different issue. You're setting `:selected_pax` but counting `:selected_person`. `count` returns zero because `:selected_person` is falsy (it isn't set at all) for both objects.

Comment: Yes, I copied from another window where I was testing and didn't noticed. All corrected now both the problem and description/screenshot match the explanation :)

Comment: The code in the question and the code in the REPL are not the same. When I run the code in the REPL, it returns 1 for the count, which would be expected when one of the objects has `selected_pax` set to true.